# Delete array value from map in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I had a code like below

```js
let  failures: Map<string, Array<string>> = new Map([
  ['1', ['a', 'b']],
  ['2', ['c', 'd']],
  ['3', ['e', 'f']]
])
```

Now lets take I has a key value like

```js
const keyItem = '2'.
```

using that keyItem how can I remove 'c' from the array of strings from the failures map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use `failures.get(keyItem)` to get the original array, then remove `c` using either `Array.prototype.splice()` or `Array.prototype.filter()` then `failures.set(keyItem, modifiedArray)` to write it back into the Map

```js
let failures: Map<string, Array<string>> = new Map([
  ['1', ['a', 'b']],
  ['2', ['c', 'd']],
  ['3', ['e', 'f']]
])

const keyItem: string = '2'

const modifiedArray: Array<string> = (failures.get(keyItem) ?? [])
  .filter(char => char !== "c")

failures.set(keyItem, modifiedArray)

console.log([...failures])
```